# Why does Jest treat 'undefined' the same as Error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm writing a unit test that looks for specific errors when certain parameters are not provided to an object. As part of the setup for my tests I pass it an object containing the input parameters and the expected error message. While writing them I left the expected error message off the provided object for one of the test cases. This test should be returning an error object with the message `'Node process.env cannot be null'`, it is being compared with an undefined object in `.toThrow()`. To my surprise this test still passed rather than throwing an error. Jest's `.toThrow()` seems to be treating `undefined` as the same value as my error message. I'm using Jest 24.9.0 for my tests.

Why does this test pass? Is this due to a behavior of Typescript/Javascript? Is this something to do with Jest?

```
it.each([
  [
    'missing event info',
    {
      event: undefined,
      env: getValidEnv(),
      expectedError: 'handler event cannot be null'
    }
  ],
  [
    'missing environment info',
    {
      event: getValidEvent(),
      env: undefined,
    }
  ]
])('should throw an error if (%s)', (testCaseName: any, params: any) => {
  const parser = new InputParser(params.event, params.env);
  expect(() => parser.getInputs()).toThrow(params.expectedError);
});
```

**Edit:**

Additional note: the same thing happens if `params.expectedError` is set to an empty string `''`.

Comment: Are you sure `params.expectedError` isn't just `undefined` for some reason?

Comment: It is undefined, that's my point. The InputParser throws the `Node.process.env cannot be null` error, and because `params.expectedError` is undefined it shouldn't match. It does though, so the unit test passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `toThrow` is optional. Passing `undefined` explicitly is effectively the same as just calling it without an argument, i.e. `xx.toThrow(undefined)` is treated the same as `xx.toThrow()`, which simply checks if any Error has been thrown. As you throw an Error, `toThrow` passes.

The call with an empty string `toThrow('')` passes, because jest checks for **substring** when a string is passed as parameter. As `''` is a substring of any string, it passes. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror.

If you want to make sure, that exactly the right error is thrown, you can use `toThrow(new Error('Node process.env cannot be null'))`.